# How to properly generate a client certificate for tls client authentication

Tags: go, ssl

I am trying to generate a client certificate in Go to use with tls client authentication.

For this I generate and sign (with some root certificate) the client certificate using this template:

```
var clientTemplate = x509.Certificate{
        SerialNumber:   big.NewInt(1),
        NotBefore:      time.Now().Add(-10 * time.Second),
        NotAfter:       time.Now().AddDate(10, 0, 0),
        KeyUsage:       x509.KeyUsageCRLSign,
        ExtKeyUsage:    []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageClientAuth},
        IsCA:           false,
        MaxPathLenZero: true,
        IPAddresses:    []net.IP{net.IP([]byte{10, 10,0,4})},
        DNSNames:       []string{},
    }
```

but when I try to verify this certificate:

```
    verifyOptions := x509.VerifyOptions{
        DNSName: "10.10.0.4",
        Roots:   certPool,
        KeyUsages: []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageClientAuth},
    }
    _, err = ClientCert.Verify(verifyOptions)
```

I get the error:

```
certificate specifies an incompatible key usage
```

But what is wrong about my key usage? What do I have to specify?

Here is a complete go test how I am trying this out:

```
func TestClientCertVerify(t *testing.T) {
    // Generate Root CA
    var rootTemplate = x509.Certificate{
        SerialNumber: big.NewInt(1),
        Subject: pkix.Name{
            Country:      []string{"DE"},
            Organization: []string{"Company Co."},
            CommonName:   "Root CA",
        },
        NotBefore:             time.Now().Add(-10 * time.Second),
        NotAfter:              time.Now().AddDate(10, 0, 0),
        KeyUsage:              x509.KeyUsageCertSign | x509.KeyUsageCRLSign,
        ExtKeyUsage:           []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageServerAuth},
        BasicConstraintsValid: true,
        IsCA:                  true,
        MaxPathLen:            2,
        IPAddresses:           []net.IP{},
        DNSNames:              []string{},
    }
    rootPrivKey, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    rootCertBytes, err := x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, &rootTemplate, &rootTemplate, &rootPrivKey.PublicKey, rootPrivKey)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to create certificate:" + err.Error())
    }

    rootCert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(rootCertBytes)
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to parse certificate:" + err.Error())
    }

    // Generate client certificate
    clientPrivKey, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var clientTemplate = x509.Certificate{
        SerialNumber:   big.NewInt(1),
        NotBefore:      time.Now().Add(-10 * time.Second),
        NotAfter:       time.Now().AddDate(10, 0, 0),
        KeyUsage:       x509.KeyUsageCRLSign,
        ExtKeyUsage:    []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageClientAuth},
        IsCA:           false,
        MaxPathLenZero: true,
        IPAddresses:    []net.IP{net.IP([]byte{10, 10,0,4})},
        DNSNames:       []string{},
    }

    clientCertBytes, err := x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, &clientTemplate, rootCert, &clientPrivKey.PublicKey, rootPrivKey)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to create certificate:" + err.Error())
    }

    ClientCert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(clientCertBytes)
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to parse certificate:" + err.Error())
    }

    // Create cert pool for verification
    certPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    certPool.AddCert(rootCert)

    // Verify a client
    verifyOptions := x509.VerifyOptions{
        DNSName: "10.10.0.4",
        Roots:   certPool,
        KeyUsages: []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageClientAuth},
    }
    _, err = ClientCert.Verify(verifyOptions)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: KeyUsage cRLSign is for signing CRLs, which is something only a CA does, and a TLS client is not a CA -- plus you have IsCA:false so you _can't_ be a CA. A **TLS client cert** (and its key) is only used to sign data, so it **should have KeyUsage digitalSignature** (i.e. bit #0 whatever the go spelling for that is). For the _CA_ cert your KU=keyCertSign|cRLSign is a valid approach, although keyCertSign alone (and a different cert for any CRLs) would also be valid.

Comment: You may find https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2021/go-https-servers-with-tls/ useful - it includes self-contained Go code to generate self-signed certs for servers and clients